# How can I perform logic inside a link to decide between "_blank" and "_self"?

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink

I want some links rendered on a page and want some to be opened in the same tab and others in a new tab. I'm familiar with `target="_blank"` and `target="_self"`. The question is how can I, inside of the `<a></a>` tag perform logic to decide how to open the tab.

For context, my code looks like so:

```
<a 
className={irrelevant}
href={link.url}
target={PERFORM LOGIC HERE: if (link.external) then "_blank" etc.}>
```

`link.external` contains a bool that determines whether that link should be `_blank` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a 
  className={irrelevant}
  href={link.url}
  target={link.external ? "_blank" : "_self"}
>
```

It is simple as that, if your link.external is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value then it will set `"_blank"` as the target else `"_self"`  will be set as the target.